# How to Use unicode with a list or a string in Python

Tags: python, list, unicode, rdf

So i Have a list of some Irish(gaelic words) words that I want to use the unicode with so that RDFlib will be able to understand the accents above some of the letters in the word. I dont know whether to use the unicode before the words are in the list or after. Here is the code I have so far:

sample line in file = `00001740 n 3 eintiteas aonán beith 003 ~ 00001930 n 0000`

```
def process_file(self):
    self.file = open("testing_line_ir.txt", "r")
    return self.file

def line_for_loop(self, file):
    for line in file:
        self.myline = unicode(line, 'utf-8')
        for line in self.myline:
        ............here is where other processes are ran.......
```

This is giving out the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 26: invalid continuation byte
```

and i have also tried this:

```
def get_words_list(self, word_part, num_words):
    self.word = word_part[3:3 + num_words:1]
    self.myword = [unicode(i) for i in self.word]
    return self.myword
```

In this case, 'word' is the list of words ['eintiteas', 'aonán', 'beith'] and I tried using myword as the encoded list, with the same error as above.

EDIT:
Here is the source code from where the error occurs, it occurs on the graph.parse line
The variables passing through like block1 and namespaces are just lines of text

```
def compose_printout(self, namespaces, block1, block2, close_rdf):
    self.printout += namespaces + block1 + block2 + close_rdf
    self.tabfile = StringIO(self.printout)
    return self.tabfile

def serialize(self, graph, tabfile):
    """ This will serialize with RDFLib """
    graph.parse(tabfile, publicID=None, format="xml")
```

Some of these words are getting added to a RDFlib graph so any help here would be great!!

Comment: Your input data is **not** UTF-8 encoded. You need to find the correct codec used for your file data.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have UTF-8 data. From the exception message I'd say you have Latin-1 encoded data instead:

```
>>> print '\xe1'.decode('latin1')
á
```

You can use the [`codecs.open()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) to create a file object that returns file data ready-decoded:

```
import codecs

def process_file(self):
    self.file = codecs.open("testing_line_ir.txt", "r", 'latin-1')
    return self.file

def line_for_loop(self, file):
    for line in file:
        # line is *already* unicode
```

Comment: now getting this error: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1' in position 331: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: @Johnnerz: You are mixing unicode and byte string values somewhere. Don't do that, implicit coercions between the types fail in ugly ways.

Comment: How can I find out where I am doing this? This is completely alien to me, I only started python 2 months ago!

Comment: @Johnnerz: Hard to tell, without your source code. The traceback tells you where the exception is being triggered (so the lines *before* the `UnicodeEncodeError`).

Comment: @Johnnerz: But generally speaking: `UnicodeEncodeError` means that something triggered a conversion from Unicode to byte string, using the ASCII codec (which is the Python default when coercing). It could be that you are trying to write your data to a file without encoding it first as well (which calls `str()` on your value, trying to encode it with the default, etc.).

Comment: @Johnnerz: If you are parsing XML then leave the decoding to the XML parser. Do not decode to Unicode yourself; the XML format indicates to the parser what to decode from. If you pass unicode data to a XML parser it'll try to coerce that back to byte strings and that could easily lead to the errors you are seeing.

Answer (score -1):

You could try these code on your file header

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

Comment: This is a bad idea for many reasons. Changing the default encoding used for Python string coercions is *not* the solution. The real solution is to explicitly encode or decode where needed.

Comment: Besides, the OP is *already* trying to explicitly decode but is using the wrong codec. How is setting the default encoding to UTF-8 going to help there?